# 12 volt connection globes and buzzer

Tags: integrated-circuit

How do you connect 3 x 12V globes together with a buzzer. The 3 globes must work separately with its own switch, but each globe must work together with only one buzzer, eg if I switch on globe 1, the buzzer must also sound (without the other globes working) ,the same if I switch on globe 2, the buzzer must sound....,

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use double-pole switches.

One pole of each switch would control one globe, while the second pole of all switches would be connected in parallel to control the buzzer.

Answer (score 0):

You use diodes in a diode-OR configuration. The basic idea is that closing SW1 will feed voltage to lamp L1, and at the same time feed voltage to the buzzer through D1. Diodes D2 and D3 block this voltage from reaching L2 and L3 so they don't turn on at the same time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwYSYv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>